# Как изменить права доступа по умолчанию Unix.

Tags: ubuntu, unix

Подскажите, как изменить права доступа для файлов по умолчанию. Для каталогов стоит 777, для файлов 666.
Мне необходимо для файлов поставить по умолчанию 777 при создании. Как это сделать?

Comment: если речь про оболочки, то — никак. см.: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/287278/110559

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Мне необходимо для файлов поставить по умолчанию 777 при создании. Как это сделать?

если коротко, то — никак. длинное изложение — ниже, а в конце упомянуты соображения по поводу того, «что, если очень хочется…».

---

в конечном (для процесса) итоге файл/каталог создаётся функцией [open()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open) (см. `$ man 1 open` и [упоминание в posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)).

при этом во втором аргументе должен быть передан (в том числе и) бит `O_CREAT` (для каталога — ещё и `O_DIRECTORY`), а третьим аргументом должен идти набор бит, задающих разрешения процессам (в зависимости от того, от чьего имени они действуют) на доступ к создаваемому файлу/каталогу.

но указанный набор бит — не «окончательный приговор». как минимум на него может оказать влияение *file mode creation mask* (*umask*) — свойство процесса (наследуемое дочерними процессами), указывающее, какие биты разрешений надо **скрыть** («за**маск**ировать») у создаваемого файла/каталога. именно «скрыть», но **не** добавить.

отсюда, надеюсь, становится чуть понятнее, почему, если мы указали процессу «ничего не скрывать» (т.е., `umask a=rwx`, или, в числовом виде — `umask 0`), каталог создаётся с битами исполнимости, а файл всё равно — без этих битов: процесс **просто не запрашивал** установку этих битов при вызове функции `open()`.

почему же не запрашивал? потому что создатели данной конкретной программы, породившей запущенный вами процесс, руководствовались [стандартом posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html):

> When a file that does not exist is created, the following features defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2008 shall apply unless the utility or function description states otherwise:
>   ...
>   3. If the file is a regular file, the permission bits of the file shall be set to: `S_IROTH | S_IWOTH | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR` (see the description of File Modes in XBD Headers, [`<sys/stat.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html)) except that the bits specified by the file mode creation mask of the process shall be cleared. If the file is a directory, the permission bits shall be set to: `S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO`

мой вольный перевод:

> когда создаётся файл, который до этого не существовал, следующие возможности (features) должны быть применены (если иное не не отмечено в описании утилиты или функции):
>   ...
>   3. если это обычный файл, должны быть выставлены следующие биты разрешений: `S_IROTH | S_IWOTH | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR` (см. описание *file modes* в [`<sys/stat.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html)) за исключением тех битов, которые должны быть скрыты (удалены) согласно значению *file mode creation mask (umask)* процесса. если файл является каталогом, должны быть выставлены биты: `S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO`

или, чуть проще:

1. обычные файлы должны иметь биты `a=rw` (синонимы: `ugo=rw` и `u=rw,g=rw,o=rw`), в числовом виде — `0666` (в восьмиричной системе счисления)
2. каталоги должны иметь биты `a=rwx` (синонимы: `ugo=rwx` и `u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx`), в числовом виде — `0777` (в восьмиричной системе счисления)
3. биты, указанные в umask, должны быть скрыты (удалены)

---

так можно ли изменить такое (подчиняющееся стандарту) поведение программ? теоретически — можно. известные мне варианты:

1. изучите документацию к программе (или её исходный код). возможно, ей можно указать (например, через конфигурационные файлы) создавать файлы с нужным вам набором бит (т.е., переопределять третий аргумент функции `open()`).
2. программу можно пересобрать, исправив умолчальное значение набора бит.
3. можно воспользоваться каким-нибудь монитором изменения файлов (например, подсистемой [inotify](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) программы *linux*) или какой-то аналогичной «пост-обработкой».

Comment: теоретически можно подменить (intercept) соответствующие системные вызовы (syscall): [`LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/your/open.so`](https://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/dynamic-linker-tricks-using-ld_preload-to-cheat-inject-features-and-investigate-programs/) (libc open) или [LKM](https://github.com/bawejakunal/Intercept-System-Calls) (если без libc)

Comment: @jfs, ну, для меня это высшая математика. напишете свой ответ с дополнительными предложениями?

Comment: я это предложил как дополнительные к вашему ответу теоретические варианты стандартное поведение изменить. Не всё что можно  сделать, следует делать.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, у меня ещё 1 голос остался незаюзанным. Кидай заявку в модеры.

Comment: @donRumata, https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6114/?noredirect=1#comment23569_6114

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ну блииииин.

Answer (score 0):

Для каждого пользователя linux можно задать маску которая будет устанавливать права на новые файлы и папки по умолчанию
например: umask 777 
На все файлы и папки при создание будет стоять 777 
Все просто вроде...

*Ссылки для просвещения:*
 [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask)
[Подробние и с примерами на все случаи](http://www.rootfront.com/article/4570101/2012-12-06/obolochki-linux-razbiraem-umask-s-primeram)

Comment: глупость написали... umask задаёт шаблон, и отбирает права от тех что есть по умолчанию,а не задаёт по умолчанию.

Comment: нет, читай внимательно вторую ссылку

Comment: вы б хоть проверили прежде чем писать.