# Как автоматически указывать права файлов, которые создаёт пользователь в Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7

Как автоматически указывать права файлов, которые создаёт пользователь? Например, разделы создаются с правами 755, а мне надо чтобы они автоматически создавались с правами 775.

Использую CentOS 7.

Comment: Создаёте командами в консоли?

Comment: Через консоль, а также через WinSCP по SSH (SFTP)

Comment: umask?. . . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой путь - пропишите в файл .bashrc (или аналогичный) строку алиса:

```
alias md='mkdir 0775'
```

И используйте команду *md*

Comment: Это будет задано для всех пользователей? Мне надо только для указанных пользователей

Comment: Политика такая: если алиас прописан в */etc/bash.bashrc* то действует на всех. Если же в */home/<пользователь>/.bashrc* - то только на этого пользователя. Тут ещё надо учитывать, чт названия этих настроечных файлов могут различаться в разных дистрибутивах.

Answer (score 3):

если под словом «разделы» подразумевались каталоги, и создаются они программой *mkdir*, запускаемой внутри оболочки, то вам надо менять свойство *umask* [для процесса оболочки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/731385/178576).

делается это внутренней командой оболочки *umask*. для получения желаемых вами восьмиричных битов `0775` (для человека естественнее мнемоника: `ug=rwx,o=rx`, или, аналогично, но более многословно: `u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx`) нужна маска `0002` (мнемонически для маски это звучит точно так же — `ug=rwx,o=rx`):

```
$ umask ug=rwx,o=rx
```

убеждаемся в изменении:

```
$ umask -S
u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx
```

и для любителей — в числовом восьмиричном виде:

```
$ umask
0002
```

и проверяем:

```
$ mkdir test
$ stat -c '%A %a' test
drwxrwxr-x 775
```

---

но как и любое изменение свойств процесса данное изменение будет действовать только на текущий процесс (и на его потомков).

а для того чтобы **новые** процессы оболочки получали требуемое свойство, надо «прописать» его

- либо глобально для всех пользователей в файле `/etc/login.defs`. там должна присутствовать директива `UMASK`, значение ей надо задавать в восьмиричном виде (если директива отсутствует, то добавьте, например, в конце файла):

  ```
  UMASK 0002
  ```
- либо персонально для нужного пользователя в файле `.profile` внутри его домашнего каталога. в этом файле частенько уже присутствует (хотя бы закомментированный) вызов внутренней команды umask. если закомментирован — раскомментируйте и укажите требуемое значени:

  ```
  umask ug=rwx,o=rx
  ```

  если нет — добавьте такую строку. смотрите только чтобы она не попала внутрь какой-нибудь условной конструкции (типа `if ... then ... else ... fi`)

Answer (score 3):

> Как автоматически указывать права файлов, которые создаёт пользователь?

Для этого есть такой параметр как `umask`. Изменяется он одноимённым [системным вызовом](http://ru.manpages.org/umask/2), а для консоли есть одноимённая команда. Значение этого параметра указывает маску для создания новых файлов т.е. биты по-умолчанию отключаемые, когда какой-либо процесс вызывает `open ()` или `mkdir ()`. Подробности см. в описании системного вызова.

Без параметров команда `umask` выводит текущее значение маски. По умолчанию в большинстве систем это `0022`.

```
$ umask
0022
```

Это даёт

```
0666 & (~0022) == 0644 == -rw-r--r-
```

Изменить значение `umask` можно передав команде новую желаемую маску. Например для создания каталогов с правами `0775` и файлов `0664` нужно будет выполнить:

```
$ umask 0002
```

Дабы значения остались постоянными, можно добавить эту команду в один из файлов инициализации. Хорошим местом будет `~/.profile`. Это даст изменения для большинства (есть кое-какие мелкие исключения) сессий текущего пользователя. Глобальное значение по-умолчанию можно задать в `/etc/login.defs` в строке `UMASK`.

Стоит заметить, что любой процесс может запросить создание файла заведомо с меньшими атрибутами, а также явно изменить их с помощью `chmod ()` после создания файла, так что `umask` — не правило, а ограничение, накладываемое по-умолчанию. Так `cp`, например по окончанию устанавливает права равные исходному файлу.

> а также через WinSCP по SSH (SFTP)

Можно также сделать это глобально в `/etc/login.defs`. А вот настроить это для одного пользователя несколько сложнее. Можно воспользоваться [PAM](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam)-модулем [pam_umask](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_umask).

Если кратко, то конфигурация будет выглядеть примерно так:

В `/etc/pam.d/sshd` (или какой-то файл, который он включает, например `common-session`, если есть желание, чтобы это относилось не только к `ssh`) добавляется вызов модуля:

```
session   optional   pam_umask.so
```

В строку дополнительной информации о пользователе (напрямую в `/etc/passwd`) или с помощью `usermod` или [`chfn`](http://ru.manpages.org/chfn/1) добавить umask=0002:

```
chfn -o umask=0002 my_username
```

В итоге для всех ssh сессий модуль pam будет устанавливать именно этот `umask`. Однако клиенты `scp` и `sftp` будут стараться устанавливать права равные изначальным с применением маски (не знаю как при этом поведут себя клиенты из не-совсем-POSIX систем).

Answer (score 0):

При создании директорий командой mkdir можно указать права, используя ключ `-m`. Например:

```
$ mkdir -m 775 test
```