# umask отдельно для файлов

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Сейчас разбираюсь с linux и возник такой вопрос по поводу umask.
Можно ли каким-либо образом сделать по умолчанию права  для папок 777, а для файлов 664. На сколько понял, что стандартными средствами это сделать  нельзя.

Есть еще dmask и fmask, но такие настройки не поддерживаются в /etc/login.defs.

Или  такого не предусмотрено и выставляются права сразу для папок и файлов (002, 022, 077).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/731544/178576 // p.s. всегда восхищался людьми, для которых rwx — не понятно, а 7 — проще пареной репы

Comment: *стандартными средствами это сделать нельзя* - что понимается под стандартными средствами? Утилита из каталога /bin ? Скрипт на шелл? Программа на С?